# Do relational operators like less than, greater than, gte, lte use type conversion in PHP?

Tags: php, operators, relational, comparison-operators

Do relational operators like less than, greater than, gte, lte use type conversion?  If they do, why are there no strict comparison relational operators like !== or === ?

Comment: What this operator should return? Let us suppose that exists strict less or equal operator. What would be result of "1" ==> 1 and 1==>"1"?

Comment: if it was "1" <== "1" then it would return true, but like !== and ===, if it was "1" <== 1, then it would return false because theyre not the same type.

Comment: And 1 <== "1" would return false too?

Comment: yes that would return false also

Comment: `$a <== $b` === false what can you say about those values?

Comment: what type is stored in $a and what type is stored in $b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they aren't strict.

They can compare most types against each other, and cast as needed. For instance there's support for string comparisons:

```
 $true = "a" < "b";
```

Internally that's `zendi_smart_strcmp()`.

If you want to do strict comparisons, you can just check the types yourself, or cast as needed.

Comment: thanks.  why is there no strict <== or >== operators?  if theyre both the same type, return the comparison, if theyre not the same type always return false.

Comment: Because strict variants aren't be commonly needed, and such operators would look super odd.